# How can I type a mapping of Object function values with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set up state in a monorepo application by composing reducers. Currently, all state is divided by domain, e.g.

```js
type State = { fruit: FruitState, snacks: SnackState })
```

Each state domain contains some selectors. These selectors are defined in an encapsulated manner, e.g.

```js
const selectApples = (state: FruitState) => state.apples;
```

We then have a `web` module which imports all the state domain selectors, grouping them by key and then wrapping them in a higher-order function to scope them into domain namespaces, e.g.

```js
function scopeSelector<T extends keyof State>(
  scopeNamespace: T,
  selectors: { [selector: string]: Function }
) {
  return Object.keys(selectors).reduce((scoped, key) => ({
    ...scoped,
    [key]: (state: State) => selectors[key](state[scopeNamespace])
  }), {});
}

export const selectors = {
  fruits: scopeSelector('fruits', fruits.selectors),
  snacks: scopeSelector('snacks', snacks.selectors)
};
```

This code works at runtime - but produces TypeScript errors, e.g.

```js
// Error: Property 'selectApples' does not exist on type '{}'.
const apples = selectors.fruits.selectApples(state);
```

I have tried using [Ramda's map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) with the advanced typings from [npm-ramda](https://github.com/types/npm-ramda). This *nearly* worked, except the return result of any selector was a union of all selectors within its "scope".

I have [set up a project on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ktjkzd?file=index.ts) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ugh what version of TS is StackBlitz using?  I have a fix but I can't be sure it it will work there.

Comment: @jcalz, not quite sure as this is the first time I've used it. However, you should be able to download the project straight from StackBlitz to run locally (there is an icon above the file tree). My project is using TypeScript version 3.5.2.

Comment: [My fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hztj7z) ... looks the same as the other answer, mostly.

Comment: @jcalz I wrote almost that exact code, decided against it since hovering over the type gives a less useful type hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript can't infer the return type of `{ [K in keyof typeof selector]: (state: RootState) => ReturnType<typeof selector[K]> }`. Unfortunately inferring any types (or even defining them without requiring a cast) when using `reduce` to build an object is almost impossible.

That said, you can get the desired behavior with a bit of casting, and declaring the return type manually.

```
function scopeSelector<
  T extends keyof RootState, 
  S extends { [selector: string]: (state: RootState[T]) => any }
>(
  scopeNamespace: T,
  selectors: S
): { [K in keyof S]: (state: RootState) => ReturnType<S[K]> } {
  return Object.keys(selectors).reduce((scoped, key) => ({
    ...scoped,
    [key]: (state: RootState) => selectors[key](state[scopeNamespace])
  }), {} as any);
}
```

Using `{} as any` removes any type safety in your `reduce` function, but you didn't have any in the first place, so I don't feel to bad about it.

Here's a StackBlitz so you can see it in action: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ke3jbf?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can!

**Type definition**

Consider the following definition:

```
declare function scopeSelector<Namespace extends keyof RootState, SubSelectors extends Selectors<any, RootState[Namespace]>>(scope: Namespace, selectors: SubSelectors): Result<SubSelectors>;
```

Where:

```
type Selectors<K extends string = string, S = any> = {
  [index in K]: (state: S) => ValueOf<S>;
}

type Result<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (state: RootState) =>
    T[K] extends AnyFunction
      ? ReturnType<T[K]>
      : never;
}

type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

**Implementation**

```
function scopeSelector<Namespace extends keyof RootState, SubSelectors extends Selectors<any, RootState[Namespace]>>(scope: Namespace, selectors: SubSelectors): Result<SubSelectors> {
  return Object.keys(selectors)
    .reduce<Result<SubSelectors>>(
      (accumulator, current) => ({
        ...accumulator,
        [current]: (state: RootState) => selectors[current](state[scope])
      }),
      {} as Result<SubSelectors>
    )
}
```